# Prisma "findUnique" is undefined on deployment

Tags: next.js, prisma, vercel

I have the following code which works in my local environment but prisma.findUnqie throws an error of undefined when deploying on Vercel:

```
    import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
    const prisma = new PrismaClient()
    ...
    const serialData = await prisma.serial.findUnique({
        where: {
            tokenId: parseInt(slice)
        }
    });
    const serial = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(serialData))
```

Then the error occurred on Vercel deployment:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/prototypes/1". 
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findUnique' of undefined
```

Any clues as to what seems to be the issue? As I can't replicate the error on local environment as everything works fine there, except on Vercel...

Comment: did you try building app locally, like `NODE_ENV=production npm run build` ?

Comment: No errors when building the app locally. I am starting to think whether I need to amend package.json and add "prisma generate" when building it in Vercel.

Comment: I am not familiar with prisma but saw docs, seems you are right "prisma generate" needs to be done before building.

Comment: That was it. I managed to deploy it. It's quite strange that I didn't need to do it in my previous deployments when handling it with Prisma. I guess there might have been a new update somewhere that I missed. Anyways, thanks for the help mate!